# Nodemailer not loggin in

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

I want to send an email from node backend and I am using the nodemailer library for express to achieve that. I have written the following code to configure the transport and other details for nodemailer

```
                let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
                  host: 'mail.myrandomhost.in',
                  port: 587,
                  tls: {
                    rejectUnauthorized:false
                },
                  secure: false,
                  auth: {
                     user: 'me@myemail.in',
                     pass: 'Gr3aseMonk3y'
                  }
              });

              const message = {
                from: 'me@myemail.in',
                to: 'youremail@gmail.com',
                subject: 'test email',
                html: '<h1>Hey</h1><p>This is test <b>Tesla</b> email</p>'
            };
            transport.sendMail(message, function(err, info) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=');
                  console.log("FAILED");
                  console.log('=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-');
                  console.log(err)
                } else {
                  console.log('====================================');
                  console.log("Email sent");
                  console.log('====================================');
                  console.log(info);
                }
            });
```

When I run this, I get the following error

```
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
FAILED
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
Error: Invalid login: 535 Incorrect authentication data
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/Users/sarthak/Desktop/CodingEnvironments/NodeJS/templates/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/Users/sarthak/Desktop/CodingEnvironments/NodeJS/templates/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1523:34)
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (/Users/sarthak/Desktop/CodingEnvironments/NodeJS/templates/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:550:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/Users/sarthak/Desktop/CodingEnvironments/NodeJS/templates/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:942:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (/Users/sarthak/Desktop/CodingEnvironments/NodeJS/templates/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:749:14)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (/Users/sarthak/Desktop/CodingEnvironments/NodeJS/templates/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:195:44)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535 Incorrect authentication data',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
}
```

I am using the correct details. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This setups would help you.

```js
// environment variable
EMAIL_HOST=yourmailserver.com  // mail.domain.com
EMAIL_PORT=465 
EMAIL_USER=noreply@domain.com
EMAIL_PASS=noreply_email_password
EMAIL_SENDER=Company_name

const transporter = createTransport({
  port: Number(process.env.EMAIL_PORT),
  host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
    pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
  },
  secure: true,
  tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
});

export async function sendMail(
  to: string,
  subject: string,
  html: any,
  attachment = null,
  isAttachment = false
) {
  const mailInfo: any = {
    from: `${process.env.EMAIL_SENDER} <${process.env.EMAIL_USER}>`,
    to: to,
    subject: subject,
    attachDataUrls: true,
    html: html,
    attachments: isAttachment ? attachment : [],
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailInfo, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("error ", error);
      
      DEBUG(error);
    }
    return true;
  });
}
```

Also note the following setting in your dns record:

- ensure your mail.domain.com is A record and point to your mail server IP
- ensure you have MX record in your DNS which point to the A record created above
- ensure the TXT record for the mail have the same IP as your mail.domain.com record. `v=spf1 a mx ip4:your_mail_IP ~all`
- if you change your nameserver to another server, ensure your old record is created on the new nameserver DNS setting, with the IP the same has old record.

`I hope this help someone`

Answer (score -2):

You entered the wrong data. you must change `host`, `from` to real addresses.
Example:

```
let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
                  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
                  port: 465,
                  tls: {
                    rejectUnauthorized:true
                },
                  secure: false,
                  auth: {
                     user: 'yourRealEmail@gmail.com',
                     pass: 'yourPassword'
                  }
              });

              const message = {
                from: 'yourRealEmail@gmail.com',
                to: 'RealEmailAddress@gmail.com',
                subject: 'test email',
                html: '<h1>Hey</h1><p>This is test <b>Tesla</b> email</p>'
            };
            transport.sendMail(message, function(err, info) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log('-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=');
                  console.log("FAILED");
                  console.log('=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-');
                  console.log(err)
                } else {
                  console.log('====================================');
                  console.log("Email sent");
                  console.log('====================================');
                  console.log(info);
                }
            });
```